# COLLATE Issues with sql server

Tags: sql-server, collate

I have 2 tables I am trying to join on `PRId`.

```
SELECT LOT_NUMBER 
FROM   Domain.dbo.LOT_TABLE
JOIN   Domain.dbo.SELINAS 
ON     Domain.dbo.SELINAS.PRId = Domain.dbo.LOT_TABLE.PRId;
```

When I run this it gives me following error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.

Adding `COLLATE` returns nothing:

```
SELECT LOT_NUMBER 
FROM   Domain.dbo.LOT_TABLE
JOIN   Domain.dbo.SELINAS 
  ON   Domain.dbo.SELINAS.PRId = Domain.dbo.LOT_TABLE.PRId 
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT;
```

I tried adding `Latin1_General_CI_AI` and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` but it still returns nothing.

If I open the table columns and look at the Extended Properties of each column, they all appear to be `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

It makes no sense...

I added

```
d2rq:join "Domain.dbo.SELINAS.PRId COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT => Domain.dbo.LOT_TABLE.PRId COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT" ;
```

like one of you suggested and it couldn't find `Domain.dbo.LOT_TABLE.PRId`

Comment: If it returns nothing then presumably the values are different.

Answer (score 2):

Add collate clause for both fields, because it doesn't affect comparison operation itself, rather field values.

```
SELECT LOT_NUMBER 
FROM   Domain.dbo.LOT_TABLE
JOIN   Domain.dbo.SELINAS 
  ON   Domain.dbo.SELINAS.PRId COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = Domain.dbo.LOT_TABLE.PRId COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: There is no need to add it on both sides. An explicit `COLLATE` clause on either side is sufficient. See [Collation Precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith Actualy, it may be necessary if both the tables have different schema that db default, and different than each other; but one collate may suffice in this example, only moved to left side.

Comment: An explicit collate clause on one side will take precedence over an implicit collation and the comparison will be carried out using the semantics of the explicit collation.